# Overactive fan on Dell Inspiron 15R

Tags: 13.10, fan

I've noticed that the fan on my Dell Inspiron 15R is working constantly when using Ubuntu 13.10. It's not a heating problem; my computer is cool. It has an ATI graphics card.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You're refusing corrections!

Comment: Hey, Not again!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Dell 15R specificatons that laptop runs using Intel HD graphics and not Ati... http://www.cnet.com/laptops/dell-inspiron-15r/4507-3121_7-34122503.html

Also, have you tried running a lighter version of Ubuntu, say Xubuntu 13.10 64-bit to see how the xfce power manager handles your fan noise...